# How to reverse this comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following code that returns a dictionary that has been subset using a list and a comprehension so that the product list only contains pairs where the key is an element in the list:

```
import collections

mydict = {'apple': 1, 'pear': 2, 'orange': 3}
mylist = ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape']

test1 = dict((x, mydict[x]) for x in mylist if x in mydict)
print test1
```

This gives an output of:

```
{'orange': 3, 'pear': 2, 'apple': 1}
```

What I now want and cant figure out how to do is a comprehension that will give me a new list of all the elements in `mylist` that are not a key within `mydict`. The output of this should look like:

```
['banana', 'grape']
```

I realise I could do this using a `for` loop and `.iteritems()` to get all the keys into a list, then use a list comprehension on `mylist` and the list created in this loop to get the second output above, but I was hoping I could do it just with a comprehension, as this would be a more elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to use `not in` don't you?

Comment: By the way, instead of making a generator of tuples and then passing that to `dict()`, you can make a dictionary comprehension directly with `test1 = {x:mydict[x] for x in...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a comprehension and a filter:

```
newlist = [key for key in mylist if key not in mydict]
```

Comment: hi there, that did just what i needed. thanks. will accept in 10 minutes when able.